# Перенос коммитов на другую ветку

Tags: git

Я скопировал репозиторий с ветки `master`.  Сделал несколько комvитов.  А после *Push Request* узнал что нужно было скопировать с ветки `development`.  Что можно предпринять, кроме как сносить всё и писать заново?

Comment: Что нужно было скопировать?

Comment: сделать rebase коммитов на новую ветку?

Comment: Переименовал вопрос в соответствии с содержимым, так как к *remotes* он не относится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перебазируйте ваши фиксации из временной ветки, которую вы создали перед внесением изменений, поверх правильной.

```
git rebase --onto development master ваша_ветка
```

Не исключено, что в процессе перебазирования могут обнаружится конфликты между вашими изменениями и изменениями из общей ветки разработки. Базовые способы их решения описаны в книге ProGit, глава [3.2 Ветвление в Git - Основы ветвления и слияния](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#r_basic_merge_conflicts).